# Cant Ping own system's IP address

Tags: networking

I am facing a problem while try to ping my own system's IP address.But when I try to ping my local IP address i.e 127.0.0.1 then its working fine.But when I give an IP address say(192.168.0.4) in my own system and try to ping the IP address from the same system i.e my system then it shows error saying that "Host cannot reachable".But if I connect my system in LAN then the ping command work properly i.e I can ping my system's IP address from my own system. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

loopback interface is special virtual interface where your applications can connect with it. Real ethernet interface can't be up if cable unplugged.  It's one way to test the internal LAN adapter health

Answer (score 0):

**use ping localhost;**

```
   As per my knowledge "ping" is works at level 3 in OSI layer i.e. next to IP. It requires external connection for loopback interface for application. But mostly I tried ping localhost without my lan connection and it works
```